# Why is the suggested edits count visible even when I have no reviews left?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I noticed this shortly after I got access to the suggested edit queue, but after searching around I can't seem to find the answer.

In the top bar, it appears that the rough count of the suggested edits queue is visible, right next to the "review" button.

[image: The suggested edits count]

After I've done my 20 suggested edits, I've noticed this icon still appears sometimes (when the suggested edit queue is high).

[image: No more suggested edit reviews available]

So my question is, **shouldn't this button be hidden if I can't help review?**

Comment: It's probably there to avoid questions in meta about "where did the suggested edits count button go?"

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature-request.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this feature has been requested before, though I can't find the duplicate at the moment.

Comment: @DennisMeng Thanks, not sure how I missed that one.